# If conditional using Awk to search for exact Bash variable string

Tags: bash, awk, etcpasswd

In writing a BASH script, I am attempting to confirm whether a username, passed as a cmd line parameter, exists on the system by referencing /etc/passwd. My syntax must be off because my code fails on existing and non-existing users.

```
username=${!#}
username_exists(){
exists=$(awk -F ':' '$1 == "$username" {print $1}' /etc/passwd | wc -l)

if [[ "$exists" == 0 ]];
then
    echo "Username does not exist"
    exit
fi
}
```

I suspect that my username variable isn't being read correctly. And/or the if comparison is wrong.
Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Don't make simple things complicated. Just use something like that: `if ! grep -q "^$username:" /etc/passwd; then echo "$username doesn't exist" >&2; exit 1; fi`

Comment: Or, perhaps, simpler: `if ! id -u "$username" &>/dev/null; then echo "$username doesn't exist" >&2; exit 1; fi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the username to awk as a variable and then let awk do all the processing.

```
awk -F ':' -v username="$username" '$1 == "$username" { fnd=1 } END { if ( fnd != 1 ) { print "Username does not exist" } }' /etc/passwd
```